# How to link firebase_messaging with mysql in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project that contains a mysql database. In this database I have a table named Comments.I try to send push notification by firebase if any user add new comment into this table.For example if User A add a new comment about topic of user B the user B will receive push notification.I am a new flutter developer so I have little experience.

What I have done so far is as follows: I have successfully connected firebase with my project now and can now send notifications to the app through the firebase console.I also write a code to get token devices.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      print(token);
    });

    notification();

    }

  notification(){
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");

      },

      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");

      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");

      },
    );
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

But now what are the steps to link the database with firebase?to get the user alerts if any change is added into the comments table in mysql.
I hope whoever knows the method will help me because I have not found any explanation about that after a long search

Answer (score 0):

The message is not sent by the cellphone, but by the firebase server. You should save the tokens of each installation of your app and build an api that saves the data in the Comment table and after saved  send the user with a specific token the notification. You should use the firebase api and send a post. Tave a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message.